# Weird maximised IE window

Tags: windows-7, windows

Okay I have tried to maximise my Window in Internet Explorer (Version 10 for reference if needed) and it appears like this:
[image]

I have never seen this happen before,

I have tried dragging to the top of the screen to activate the snap in in Windows 7, closing and reopening the session/ Window, used windows key + up arrow to activate snap ins that way to no avail... Maximising with the button in top left also sets the window to this level...

what is happening to my Windows? and how do I restore to full screen when maximising the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open regedit and go to

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

There's a binary key `Window_Placement`. Try deleting the value and close registry. This should reset saved window settings and the next time you open your IE, the previous defaults would be gone. If you want to save your IE window settings, hold the `Ctrl` key while closing IE.

Comment: Just wondering does holding the control key when closing save all window settings or is it exclusive to IE window?

Comment: Other microsoft products like word, excel etc seem to be saving the settings while exiting even if you don't press the control key. I think it might be the way each application programmer define the `exit` behavior.